# MessageCountListener is not working with outlook email address

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, office365, jakarta-mail

By using jarata mail library I have developed a java library which will also allows for new mail notification. For that purpose on a thread I have subscribed to `ImapFolder.addMessageCountListener()` like below:

```
folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                //processing of received new messages
            }
 });
```

On same thread I am executing `IDLE` command on same folder:

```
while (!stopNotificationListener && !Thread.interrupted()) {
                try
                {
                    notificationFolder.idle();
                }
                catch (FolderClosedException e)
                {
                    noopThread.shutdown();
                    logger.error("Lost connection with server, re-connecting again.");
                }
 }
```

Some days ago I tested this with outlook and gmail email address it was working.

But today when I am testing with outlook email address, `addMessageCountListener` is not triggering. But there is no issues with gmail email address.

Below is the debug log:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UABOADAAUABSADAAMQBDAEEAMAAwADAANwAuAEkATgBEAFAAUgBEADAAMQAuAFAAUgBPAEQALgBPAFUAVABMAE8ATwBLAC4AQwBPAE0A]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=amogh.shah@company.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPProtocol noop
A3 NOOP
A3 OK NOOP completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
A4 LOGOUT
* BYE Microsoft Exchange Server IMAP4 server signing off.
A4 OK LOGOUT completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup done
DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UABOADAAUABSADAAMQBDAEEAMAAwADEAOAAuAEkATgBEAFAAUgBEADAAMQAuAFAAUgBPAEQALgBPAFUAVABMAE8ATwBLAC4AQwBPAE0A]
B0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
B0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=amogh.shah@company.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: B1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
B2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
B2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
B3 EXAMINE Inbox
* 1272 EXISTS
* 1272 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 17102] The next unique identifier value
B3 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed.
B4 IDLE
+ IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
DEBUG IMAPS: IMAPStore cleanup, not connected
```

What is the correct way to keep connection idle, which would work with every email server ?

**Observation:**

MessageCountListener is not triggering only when I use organization's email address, when I use my personal outlook email address then listener is triggered.

Comment: Just use `idle()`. That's what it's for. I don't know why you added the NOOP thing.